# How to set auto-increment to value other than one in EF Core Fluent API

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the Fluent API to define my db entity. Now I need to set the increment for my identity to a value that is not one.

I would like to have the SQL equivalent of `my_id int IDENTITY(1,2)`.

The following code always generates an `IDENTITY(1,1)`

```
builder.HasKey(m => m.MyId);
builder.Property(m => m.MyId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Answer (score 1):

`builder.Property(m => m.MyId).UseIdentityColumn(1, 10);`